# How should i choose between client side SDK and server side API?

Tags: api, facebook

i have a rails web app that I want to deeply integrate with facebook (create events, wall post...)

How should i choose between Facebook JavaScript SDK and the Graph API ?
When should I use client side API and when server side

Answer (score 4):

Graph API is an API, JS SDK is an SDK.

API is a way to access to the data. It can be used from JS, as well as from the server-side.

SDK is a set of tools to work with something.

So comparing API and SDK is a "little" out of logic.

When you need data on the server side - you perform an API request from the server side, when you need data on client side - you perform an API request from the client side.

Sorry of being "Captain Obvious".

Comment: That's nothing new. There are actions that can be done either way. 
For example I want to create a new event. The user can do it on the client side or send the server the data and it will do it. 
What are the pro/ cons of each approch?

Comment: @Gady: there are no any significant pros and cons. Just do what is better **for you**.

Comment: Yeah I think Gady meant JavaScript SDK vs. Facebook for Rails API. I'd first select which Rails API you're going to use, and read _their_ documentation / forums for what works best. You're probably going to use the JS SDK for some things no matter what.